# python matplotlib x and y axis ticks modification

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a question. I have a text file containing three columns for X,Y and Z as follows:

```
  0.25000000000000000         0.25000000000000000          12.776427951155485     
  0.25000000000000000         0.75000000000000000          30.845025638362273     
  0.75000000000000000         0.25000000000000000          12.776427951155489     
  0.75000000000000000         0.75000000000000000          30.845025638362277
```

To plot the contour, I am using the following:

```
f = plt.contour(Z,origin='lower')
```

And get the following figure: 
[image]

My question is that the x and y labels are the indices of the arrays containing the X and Y values. How can I transform it so the ticks are the values of the X and Y.

Comment: Here's the documentation for `contour`: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.contour.html?highlight=contour#matplotlib.axes.Axes.contour

I believe the `extent` option is what you want

Comment: That worked, many thanks